# What is the best way of having a large list of HD images in your C# application?

Tags: c#, image, caching

Having a C# application that on startUp loads a large list of images (100+ images) into an itemView control with large tiles, I believe i could add the images to the app's resources but i can also create a hidden background folder in the appData of user which i believe would slow down the loading process and we do not want that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!
Best way is to first create a List or whatever the list is that you need to save in the applications cache.

Then programmatically update a resource object like this:

```
    IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("Resources.Images");
    writer.AddResource("ImgList", ImageList);
    writer.Generate();
```

You can then use ResourceReader to retrieve the list perfectly! and fast.